# Visual Studio throwing an error "Use of unassigned var"

Tags: c#

Okay, so I have an assignment for programming class to create a calculator using methods for different operations.
On this line:

```
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", num1, op, num2);
```

I'm receiving
Error   2   Use of unassigned local variable 'op'

I can't figure out why, here's the entire code:
Thanks for the help in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LabAssignFiveCalc
{
    class Program
    {
        //Addition method
        static double Addition(int num1, int num2)
        {
            double result;
            result = num1 + num2;
            return result;
        }
        //Subtraction method
        static double Subtract(int num1, int num2)
        {
            double result;
            result = num1 - num2;
            return result;

        }
        //Multiplication method
        static double Multiply(int num1, int num2)
        {
            double result;
            result = num1 * num2;
            return result;
        }
        //Division method
        static double Divide(int num1, int num2)
        {
            double result;
            result = num1 / num2;
            return result;

        }
        //Main
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declare Variables
            int choice;
            string op;
            double num1;
            double num2;
            double result;
            //Ask user for calculation parameters
            Console.WriteLine("Calculator:");
            Console.WriteLine("Which operation do you wish to perform? Type the corresponding number.");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Addition\n2) Subration\n3) Multiplication\n4) Division");
            choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please type the first number you wish to calculate");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please type the second number you wish to calculate");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            //Declare Operator
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    op = "+";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    op = "-";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    op = "*";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    op = "/";
                    break;
            }
            //Show Calculation
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", num1, op, num2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized variables. That's why you need to initialize your `op` variable before you use it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have `default` option in `switch` block, so `op` variable can be not assigned if user will enter something other than 1, 2, 3 or 4.

I suggest you to use loop to ask user again if he entered invalid value:

```
int choice;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("1)Addition\n2)Subration\n3)Multiplication\n4)Division");
    choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
while (choice < 1 && 4 < choice);
```

Next is adding default case:

```
switch (choice)
{
    case 1: op = "+"; break;
    case 2: op = "-"; break;
    case 3: op = "*"; break;
    case 4: op = "/"; break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException();       
}
```

Alternatively you can treat all values which are not 1, 2, or 3 as division operation:

```
switch (choice)
{
    case 1: op = "+"; break;
    case 2: op = "-"; break;
    case 3: op = "*"; break;
    default:
        op = "/"; break;
}
```

Instead of adding default case you can assign default value when declaring variable:

```
string op = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Rule :** You should always initialise  all of your local variables.

if you observe your code `num1` and `num2` are initialised properly before the switch block but you are assigning `op` value in the `switch` block.

compiler can not identify wether whcih block gets executed untill you run your program.

hence you should either intialise the `op` before the switch block or you should declare default block to make sure the initialisation at compile time.

**Solution 1:**

Replace This:

```
string op;
```

With This:

```
string op = string.Empty;
```

**Solution 2:**

```
       switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                op = "+";
                break;
            case 2:
                op = "-";
                break;
            case 3:
                op = "*";
                break;
            case 4:
                op = "/";
                break;
            default:
                op = "";
                break;
        }
```